# Need to know when no data appears between two token separators using strtok()

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to tokenize a string but I need to know exactly when no data is seen between two tokens. e.g when tokenizing the following string "`a,b,c,,,d,e`" I need to know about the two empty slots between '`d`' and '`e`'... which I am unable to find out simply using `strtok()`. My attempt is shown below:

```
char arr_fields[num_of_fields];
char delim[]=",\n";
char *tok;
tok=strtok(line,delim);//line contains the data

for(i=0;i<num_of_fields;i++,tok=strtok(NULL,delim))
{
    if(tok)
        sprintf(arr_fields[i], "%s", tok);
    else
        sprintf(arr_fields[i], "%s", "-");          
}
```

Executing the above code with the aforementioned examples put characters a,b,c,d,e into first five elements of `arr_fields` which is not desirable. I need the position of each character to go in specific indexes of array: i.e if there is a character missing between two characters, it should be recorded as is.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya: That's not very useful advice unless it's accompanied by a reason...

Comment: You mean "between 'c' and 'd'" ?

Comment: It is extremely accurate advice.  The trouble is that `strtok()` is designed to ignore repeats of the token separator characters, and it obliterates them.  Therefore, if you need to know about adjacent token separators, or if you need to know which separator marked the end of a token, you cannot use `strtok()` for the job.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**7.21.5.8 the strtok function**

The standard says the following regarding `strtok`:

> [#3] The first call in  the  sequence  searches  the  string
>          pointed  to  by  `s1`  for  the  first  character  that is not
>          contained in the current separator string pointed to by  `s2`.
>          If  no  such character is found, then there are no tokens in
>          the string pointed to by `s1` and the `strtok` function  returns
>          a  null  pointer.   If  such a character is found, it is the
>          start of the first token.

In the above quote we can read you cannot use `strtok` as a solution to your specific problem, since it will treat any sequential characters found in `delims` as a **single** token.

---

#### Am I doomed to weep in silence, or can somebody help me out?

You can easily implement your own version of `strtok` that does what you want, see the snippets at the end of this post.

`strtok_single` makes use of `strpbrk (char const* src, const char* delims)` which will return a pointer to the first occurrence of any character in *delims* that is found in the null-terminated string *src*.

If no matching character is found the function will return NULL.

---

**strtok_single**

```
char *
strtok_single (char * str, char const * delims)
{
  static char  * src = NULL;
  char  *  p,  * ret = 0;

  if (str != NULL)
    src = str;

  if (src == NULL)
    return NULL;

  if ((p = strpbrk (src, delims)) != NULL) {
    *p  = 0;
    ret = src;
    src = ++p;

  } else if (*src) {
    ret = src;
    src = NULL;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

**sample use**

```
  char delims[] = ",";
  char data  [] = "foo,bar,,baz,biz";

  char * p    = strtok_single (data, delims);

  while (p) {
    printf ("%s\n", *p ? p : "<empty>");

    p = strtok_single (NULL, delims);
  }
```

**output**

```
foo
bar
<empty>
baz
biz
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It is a simple example of an implementation following the rules set out by `strtok` but that confirms to what OP wishes for. Yes, `strtok` is not thread-safe, though that is a completely different matter than what OP is asking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I never said anything to contradict what you are saying, I am well aware of the pitfalls that pop up (or down) when using `strtok`.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp I have a question on one of your answers. Can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294129/i-need-a-mix-of-strtok-and-strtok-single

Comment: Note that this version of `strtok_single()` doesn't return the segment after the last delimiter.  There's a fixed version in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30295426/15168), along with demonstration code of the problem.

Comment: @ChristopheQuintard well spotted, I think that particular fix got lost in some historic revision (it has now been fixed, [see history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8706031/revisions)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just noticed that you provided a fix for the bug addressed by [@ChristopheQuintard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2017567/christophe-quintard), though functional I think you are interested in my fix that I just edited in.

Comment: That looks approximately equivalent, though different in detail.  The results look the same, which is good.  (I can only upvote once — you already had it — because the "write your own if the standard tool doesn't do the job" advice is entirely valid, albeit to be used with caution.  You need to make sure there isn't an alternative standard tool that you could use instead before reinventing the wheel.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `strtok()` if that's what you want. From the man page:

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter characters in the parsed
>       string is considered to be a single delimiter.  Delimiter characters at
>       the  start  or  end  of  the  string are ignored.  Put another way: the
>       tokens returned by strtok() are always nonempty strings.

Therefore it is just going to jump from `c` to `d` in your example.

You're going to have to parse the string manually or perhaps search for a CSV parsing library that would make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

Lately I was looking for a solution to the same problem and found this thread.

You can use `strsep()`.
From the manual:

> The strsep() function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(3),
>   since the latter cannot handle empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706031/6210), you'll want to implement something like `strtok` yourself. I prefer using `strcspn` (as opposed to `strpbrk`), as it allows for fewer `if` statements:

```
char arr_fields[num_of_fields];
char delim[]=",\n";
char *tok;

int current_token= 0;
int token_length;
for (i = 0; i < num_of_fields; i++, token_length = strcspn(line + current_token,delim))
{
    if(token_length)
        sprintf(arr_fields[i], "%.*s", token_length, line + current_token);
    else
        sprintf(arr_fields[i], "%s", "-");
    current_token += token_length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse (for example, strtok)
2. **Sort**
3. Insert
4. Rinse and repeat as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `strchr` to find out the locations of the `,` symbols. Tokenize manually your string up to the token you found (using `memcpy` or `strncpy`) and then use again strchr. You will be able to see if two or more commas are next to each other this way (strchr will return numbers that their subtraction will equal 1) and you can write an `if` statement to handle that case.

Comment: Since the delimiters can be comma or newline, `strchr()` is not the appropriate tool to use.

Comment: can't strchr() locate the '\n' value?

Comment: Yes, `strchr()` can find commas, and it can find newlines, but to find the next 'comma or newline', you have to call `strchr()` twice, once to look for the comma, once for the newline.

Comment: Cant you use a 'case' statement? I think it is not the most appropriate tool to use but it can solve the problem alright.

Comment: There are other string functions - `strspn()`, `strcspn()`, `strpbrk()` in particular - that do most of the needed job.  Yes, I'm sure you could write it using a `case` statement, but it isn't what springs to mind.

Comment: +1 because you are right :) I always tend to use the most simplistic tool and build by hand around it to try and make it work as I want it to. This, obviously, gets me in a lot of trouble...