# reading CSV with scanf and scanset with multiple decimals

Tags: c, scanf

Following the scanset format in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973130/how-to-extract-fields-in-comma-separated-string-using-sscanf-and-scanset-when-so), I tried a slightly different format to read several numbers instead of one. Here's my data:

```
722280,"BIRMINGHAM MUNICIPAL AP",AL,-6.0,33.567,-86.750,189
```

Here's my code:

```
char buf[400];
char station[11], city[101], state[11];
int tz, lat, lon, alt;
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) // yes, I test this 
sscanf( buf, "%10[^,],%100[^,],%10[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d", station, city, state, &tz, &lat, &lon, &alt);
```

When I run this, station, city, state and tz are all set properly. However, lat, lon and alt are not - lat is 1 for instance, lon is 0.

I tried a number of variations on the string, including [^,] after the %d, and removing the commas, without luck.

Yes, I know I can do this with `strtok` or one of the many variants, but I'd like to try a sscanf as it matches a similar set of code and I'd like to keep them similar, if possible.

I suspect this is possible and I'm doh'ing on the format?

Comment: They are floating point, not `int`. You are using `%d` format in `sscanf`.

Comment: OMG. That's what you get for a C&P.

Comment: ALWAYS check the return value fom `scanf` family: the number of items successfully converted.

Comment: I do the test in real code, this is my sim. Hmmm, so I did this: "%10[^,],%100[^,],%10[^,],%d,%f,%f,%d" and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: You have 3 floating point values in the text input example, but only 2 `%f` in the commented "real code". And are they `int` or `float` or `double`? The variables are all `int`.

Comment: I suggest `11` is not enough for a state name such as "New Hampshire". You restrict the input length, but the unread data remains in the input buffer, to be read for the next format specifier: the excess data is not discarded.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, always post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem to help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right format as suggest, as well as right data types. This should work:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char buf[400];
    char station[11], city[101], state[11];
    float tz, lat, lon;
    int alt;

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file))
    {
        sscanf(buf, "%10[^,],%100[^,],%10[^,],%f,%f,%f,%d", 
            station, city, state, &tz, &lat, &lon, &alt);

        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n%f\n%f\n%d\n\n", station, city, state, tz, lat, lon, alt);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would need further processing on `city` to remove the quotes. Reading the city into a `tmp` variable and then using `strncpy (city, tmp +1, strlen (tmp) - 2)` or something similar would do. (unless you want useless double-quotes hanging off each end of the string)

Comment: regarding: `FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "fopen test.txt for read failed" );`  This will output the enclosed text AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`.  Follow that call with `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`