# Would strtok() be useful for parsing out periods but keeping them? (C)

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to remove all the whitespace in a string that is made out of multiple sentences, but I would also like to keep the periods separate from each of the tokens. Would strtok() still be useful for this or is there another function I should know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know where the periods are, and treat them as separate tokens, then `strtok()` is not the right function.  It zaps the delimiters with nulls; you don't get told which delimiter it found.

You probably need to look at:

- [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html)
- [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html)
- [`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html)

You could also look at other questions about `strtok()` and its alternatives.  There are many.  [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) is a dangerous function.  You can't afford to use in a function called from another function that is also using `strtok()`, nor can you afford to call any other function that uses `strtok()`.  You should look up POSIX [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) or Microsoft's [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx); they're safe for use in library functions.  You could also look up `strsep()`.

You might find one of these questions useful:

- [I need a mix of `strtok()` and `strtok_single()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294129)
- [Need to know when no data appears between two token separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705844)

And there are many others that could help.

Comment: I don't know why `strtok` is considered above all else by so many people. It's non-reentrant and requires that the string be mutable.

Comment: @Seb: yes; it is puzzling that `strtok()` is the first port of call so often.  It is so seldom the best way of doing the job.

Comment: @Seb There's an enormous amount of wrong technical advice out there, even here on Stack Overflow. "This function has the shortest name, I'll just use it!" – says everyone ever. People also don't RTFM, don't care about `strtok()` draggin' a `static` internal thread-unsafe state with it because "it worked for me". And when used in a real-life scenario, they are surprised it fails. Go figure…

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[] ="- This. is a s.ample string.";
char * pch;
printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
pch = strtok (str," ,-"); //any other tokens you want to use here
while (pch != NULL)
{
  printf ("%s\n",pch);
  pch = strtok (NULL, " ,-");
}
```

Comment: The OP did specify that it should be in C.

Comment: How does this 'keep the periods separate from each of the tokens'?  It simply zaps the periods (and commas, dashes and spaces), doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have to go with a more trivial implementation by simply going character by character through the string. I'd be interested to read any other solutions you guys come up with though.

Comment: Well i never used strtok a lot, but i mostly work in C++, so don't have to. But i guess for his issue, calling strtok without period is all he need, but anyways now i guess he found what he was looking for